# Mongodb C# - How to get max date - ( Aggregate )

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

The documents look like this:

```
{
  ContractNumer: 10,
  SomeField: "ABC",
  ValueContract: 17.7,
  DataProcessing: '2021-01-19 10:23:20:10',
  Status: 1
}
```

With C# mongodb driver, how do you write something like this?

```
Select ContractNumer, SomeField, ValueContract, DataProcessing, Status
FROM TAB T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELCT ContractNumer, MAX(DataProcessing) AS MAX_DATE FROM TAB) SUB_T
ON T1.ContractNumer = SUB_T.ContractNumer 
AND T1.DataProcessing = SUB_T.MAX_DATE 
WHERE ....
```

So that for each combination (group) of `ContractNumber` we'll get max of `DataProcessing`

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/84p4I3F-RQE) will help you

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$ContractNumer", //Group
      "max": {
        "$max": "$DataProcessing" //Find max
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it out in `c#` and post the question with your attempts.

Comment: This way, the query brings only the ContractNumer field, but I need all the fields